# Geometry Nodes How do I get the scale of this modified Object

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanna use the Scale values of **this object** which has **this** Geometry Nodes Modifier on it.
Like this Object Info Node, which uses other Objects, just empty doesnt work, is 0.0.0

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/object_info.html

How do I get the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dirty way

Found one little hack.

So as you understand, all objects inside current object is in object itself coordinate system. So if the current object is scaled, this means that everything outside this object is in inverted scale.

So I just add a helper object (basically an empty with default scale) and use its relative scale to get the scale of the current object by dividing 1 by the scale:

[image: screen shot of the dirty way]

### Proper way

The only proper way to do this, as I have found, is to pass object socket into group input:

[image: Connecting object socket to input group]

And then set object itself in the modifier:

[image: Setting the object in the modifier]

Sure, it requires manual work, but it is better than nothing.

### Simple way

Of course, you can just select object in the input field if you are not going to reuse this geometry nodes on other objects.

Comment: Thats the thing, it is also on other different objects. it should get directly the modified object scale.

I really wondered why this not exist or I miss something.

It should get directly this Object, if input field is empty or an 'this' attribute.

Its also in C# like this, you use 'this' for the object-oriented reference.

Comment: So, using modifier inputs, you can select each object.

Comment: Empty field is regarded as no object, it may be useful in some cases

Comment: Okay, like the Normal Map Node in Shader Editor an empty UV Map input is like the existing UV Map, because Normal Map needs any UV unwrap.

So would be cool to have a 'this' attribute in Geometry Nodes Object Info Node.

Comment: No, empty UV is active UV, marked by render icon in properties.

Comment: Ah okay, big thanks for this information.

Comment: I've updated the answer BTW

Comment: Oh wow that works fine. Thank you much